# Does spring have any utility methods for getting a constructor with parameters?

Tags: java, spring

There are a lot of useful reflection utilities in Spring that make the normal security exceptions or missing method exceptions an unchecked exception. Example

```
BeanUtils.instantiate( Foo.class );
```

does not require a try/catch. However

```
BeanUtils.instantiateClass( Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor( arg.getClass() ), arg )
```

will require catching a NoSuchMethodException, that's thrown by `getDeclaredConstructor`

is there a spring utility for getting constructors that allows me to not deal with a checked Exception?

Comment: To be clear, it's acquiring the `Constructor` that can throw the exception.

Comment: which Spring version are you asking about?

Comment: @SergeyPauk we're currently using 3.2, but even if this were only available in 4 that'd be nice to know

Comment: there's no signature in this version like your second one. Did you mean `instantiateClass`? It throws  `BeanInstantiationException` which is an unchecked one so I don't quite get your question.

Comment: @SergeyPauk copy pasta evil, I was correcting the question, whilst you were commenting, and yeah it's "getting the constructor" that's throwing the exception.